# How do you read a manga when a big section is adjacent to several small ones?

Tags: naruto-gaiden, panel-arrangement

Like this

[image]

Also, if this big section had small sections at both sides instead of one, how would you read it then? Or what if the big section was on the right side?

Comment: A lot of times, if you're unsure how to follow the panels (which often means the artist wasn't very good, but that's a separate problem), you can try following the flow of dialogue. In the given example, it's fairly clear that "Over here!" is meant to follow "Hey, Chouchou!", and then it follows that you should read top to bottom, right to left. (If you can't do this, it usually means the writer wasn't very good, but that's a separate problem.)

Comment: Well..you can actually also say "Over here!!" first to attract attention and then say "Hey chouchou!!" but I get the idea :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Manga are usually published in the same style as historical texts/long novels for Japanese and Chinese readers (I am a Chinese but ya, most of our readings nowadays are from left to right). For that reason, the flow of the structure is always from top to bottom, right to left. In the case where the page is split into 2 sections by an invisible (horizontal) line in the middle, It is always read from top to bottom of the upper section, then followed by top to bottom of the lower section.

[image: Order of reading]

Of course, some manga use slanted lines to guide the reader on which boxes to read next  :)